# stacking of routes in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.user)
    if(!req.user){
        res.redirect('/login');
     }else{
        res.locals.username = req.user.username;
        return next();
     }
});

//this won't work
router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register');
});
```

The first block make sense and it's working,I able to have a login system with protected routes. But in the same time it ruined my second bit, it will show the login page althought I try to nagivate to localhost:3000/register.

Comment: Put your router.get before you router.use and it won't be called for your route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `router.use()` you're telling the router to use that function middleware in all the next `roter.get()` routes. So here, the order makes sense. If you care about order you can do what @bloodyKnuckles do. Or if you want to keep that pattern for your routes you can do the following :

```
// Routes that don't need authorization like register
router.get('home',...);
router.get('register',...);

// Use your authorization middleware
router.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.user)
  if(!req.user){
    res.redirect('/login');
  }else {
    res.locals.username = req.user.username;
    return next();
  }
});

// At this point you're using the authorization middleware. 
// Any routes declared from here will call authorization middleware before its handler.
router.get('profile', ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the express route middleware option to distinguish protected routes from unprotected routes.

```
// unprotected routes (no auth middleware)
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register');
});

// protected route (see auth middleware here)
router.get('/userinfo', authorize, function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('userinfo');
});

function authorize (req, res, next){
    console.log(req.user)
    if(!req.user){
        res.redirect('/login');
     }else{
        res.locals.username = req.user.username;
        return next();
     }
}
```

Include your authorization middleware ONLY in the protected routes:

```
router.get(path, [middleware (optional),] callback)
```

Comment: Putting your auth in `router.use` makes order matter. If you put your auth in `router.get`, order of your routes no longer matters.